# Configuring cantaloupe

Tags: header, cors

Product: https://cantaloupe-project.github.io/

I was looking for it, but cannot find the answer and I hope that someone has a similar problem.

I am wondering if it is possible to configure from server-side Access-Allow-Origin-Headers? Right now the server is returning '*', while I would like to specify a list of servers.
Thanks!

EDIT:

Ok, I will add more details here:

1. I'd like to specify only one address, so this will not be a problem.
2. I'm sending that set to the server, but in the response, I get `*`. I am using authorization, so I would expect to have configured the address in the response, not the wildcard.
3. I'm running cantaloupe standalone.
4. I would prefer to omit middle points in architecture (e.g. Nginx etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

[image]

As you can see, you can set a specific origin there. However, using several possible origins is not allowed. As a result, you will need to be a little bit unconventional in order to achieve this. Possible solutions:

## Allow everything in the header, filter in the app

You can leave the * as the header value, yet, in the application you can check to see where the request was sent from.

## You can have a middle point in your architecture

So, if you have domain1, domain2, ..., domainn possibly requesting to you, then you could ensure that the request is sent to those domains and they would forward the request on server-side to your site, which would completely bypass browser limitations. However, in order to achieve this, you need to either have control over the source-code of the domains or you need the ability to enforce this new standard for the user domains.